# gsoap : plug in stlvector

Tags: visual-studio-2010, import, gsoap

I'm writting hellow-world program using gsoap v 2.8 and trying to compile it in Visual Studio 2010. I want to use stl-vector functionality. But there are import errors in directive

```
#import "import/stlvector.h"
```

The error:

> error C1083: Cannot open type library file: 'r:\work\vs2010\xmlme\xmlme\import\stlvector.h' Error while loading library r:\work\vs2010\xmlme\xmlme\xmlme.h

And consequence:

> IntelliSense: cannot open source file "R:/Work/VS2010/XmlMe/XmlMe/Debug/stlvector.tlh" r:\work\vs2010\xmlme\xmlme\xmlme.h

Cannot figure out what Intellisense wants from me. I copied import folder from gsoap directory to my project and referencing it properly as I think.

[my solution archive (link may expire)](http://tbf.me/a/DlQEN)

**UPDATE:**

I've tried -s parameter for wsdl2h utility to exclude stl-dependency from xmlme.h file. And now I've similar error:

> error C1083: Cannot open type library file: soap12.h: Error while loading library. xmlme\xmlme.h

... producing the same weird consequence:

> IntelliSense: cannot open source file "XmlMe/Debug/soap12.tlh" \xmlme\xmlme.h

Answer (score 0):

The thing is to not include XmlMe.h (file generated with wsdl2h.exe tool) in the project. It uses soapcpp2-compliant language (C-based but not C and that's why VS10 compiler generates error when including such a file).

Also you need to include .nsmap file, for e.g. in your main function definition file.